# If p and q and primes, is there $s,t∈{Z}$ such that $s(p+1)+t(q+2)=1?$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

Title says it all, have an exam tomorrow and am practicing but can't wrap my head around this one.

Let p and q be two different odd prime numbers. Is there an $s,t∈{Z}$ such that $s(p+1)+t(q+2)=1?$

I tried writing it out as $sp+s+tq+2t=1$ and got that $sp+tq=1$ (Bezouts thm) and then $s+2t=0$, but have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: p = 5, q = 7 forms a counterexample because 6 and 9 aren't relatively prime

Comment: Is it always true that $p + 1$ and $q + 2$ are coprime? If not then it should be very easy to find a counterexample.

Comment: Stephen! You're back! Thank you so much :D I guess q+1 and p+2 are not necessarily always coprime, like if we have 11+1=12 and 13+2=15 :0 Those are divisible by 3 Is that enough to answer the question?

Comment: And thank you Jeroen as well for the counterexample :D

Comment: Oh hey! Thought it might've been you, didn't think to check though. So yes, that is all we need, by the same argumentation we went over before. We can also say that there will be infinitely many counterexamples because of the Dirichlet prime number theorem, which guarantees that there will be infinitely many primes equivalent to both $1$ and $2$ mod $3.$ (we can also use this to reach our conclusion without explicitly constructing a counterexample)

Comment: Ohh thank you so much for the general solution! :0 It seems like our book has never mentioned Dirichlet, aside from the Pigeonhole Principle, but this will be very useful as I've often struggled with tasks relating to this :D Once again, thank you so much, you'll probably see more of me here when my Calculus exam in January is coming up hahah! ;p